# What is best way to performance and load test AWS cloud applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, testing, aws-lambda, performance-testing

Want to keep this question generic and expected answer in terms of best practice/approach/guidelines,

We need to know the best way to performance test and load test AWS cloud based applications.

**What we have tried:**

We used Gatling and Jmeter to execute our performance tests. These frameworks are pretty useful to test our functionality and to benchmark our applications latency and request rate.

**Problem:**

Performance benchmarks and limits of AWS managed services like Lambda and DDB are already specified by AWS e.g. Lambda concurrency behavior and DDB autoscaling under load etc. AWS also provides high availability and guaranteed performance of managed services.

1. Is it really worth executing expensive performance test and load test jobs for AWS managed services?
2. How to ensure that we are testing our application and not actually testing AWS limits which are already known.
3. What is the best practice and approach to performance test cloud based applications.

Any suggestions will help tremendously.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you can use the AWS infrastructure

1. If you don't use [Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) you can treat the AWS cloud-based application as a "normal" application just deployed not on your company premises, but somewhere at Amazon
2. If you use Auto Scaling you might want to come up with a some form of [scalability testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing). AWS instances can scale up in order to adapt to the increased load but your application must be able to scale as well. So you can test:

   - how fast are scale-up and scale-down processes, i.e. if you rapidly increase the load do AWS/your application react fast enough or there will be performance drop
   - scalability factor. For example with 100 virtual users you have 50 requests per second. Ideally with 200 virtual users you should have 100 requests per second, with 300 virtual users - 150 requests per second. Response time should remain the same. But normally the situation differs from the "ideal" so it would be good to know this scalability factor.

Also if your application is behind the [AWS ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) you will need to add [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps/) to your JMeter test plan otherwise you will be hitting only one backend instance while others will be idle.